# Can a CSS pseudo-class be declared on an HTML element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Is it possible to set a CSS pseudo-class on an HTML element? In this particular case, I would like a certain `<div>` to have the last-child property.

I asked myself this question when IE11 wouldn't recognize a specific `<div>` as a last-child while other browsers did. I have found a work around and at this point I just want to know whether setting a pseudo-class on an HTML element can be done.

A coworker suggested this may be in fact done using React framework. However, I have not been able to find anything suggesting this is possible.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem and add the code to your question? Difficult to find a solution without seeing code

Comment: I did not add any code because I don't believe it would contribute anything to what is a conceptual question.

Comment: IE11 shouldn't have problems with last-child, so maybe there are some HTML elements in IE11 that are not present in the other browsers?

Comment: I suspect that you misunderstand what `last-child` means/does. It only **selects** the last element in a container so you can style it. It does not **define** an element as the last child.

Comment: Thank you Paulie, that answers my question. I'm more or less asking if I'm thinking about it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Pseudo-classes are used to define the state of an element.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

This would also have to either be in a JS or CSS file, not an HTML file as far as I know.

For example, I was using `:nth-child(4)` on an `img` and can't see it being different with `div`.

This is how I was using it in my JS:

```
$('#recipeStack img:nth-child(4)').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(160px, -160px)',
  'transition-delay' : '0.3s',
  'opacity' : '1'
});
```

And should turn out fine in your case in a CSS file too:

```
.parent > div:last-child {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```